# How to split a column into two columns based on the value in the another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012

I have below data in the Ms SQL server table.

[image]

I would like to get the output like below.

[image]

I have tried two sets of queries but it didn't helped me.

1st set query gives me the null values

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    [id]
  , [sav]
  , [cat]
  , [tech]
  , [asset]
  , CASE
        WHEN [objname] = 'FieldName'
        THEN [stringvalue]
    END AS [fieldname]
  , CASE
        WHEN [objname] = 'FieldValue'
        THEN [stringvalue]
    END AS [fieldvalue]
FROM [test].[dbo].[sample];
```

**Output**

[image]

2nd set query gives me 0 as field value, because i have hard coded it.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [fieldname]) AS 'id'
  , [sav]
  , [cat]
  , [tech]
  , [asset]
  , [fieldname]
  , 0 AS [fieldvalue]
FROM [test].[dbo].[sample] PIVOT(MAX([stringvalue]) FOR [objname] IN(
    [fieldname])) [p]
WHERE [fieldname] IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output**

[image]

How to achieve it ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What is a logic to connect one row with `FieldName` to another with `FieldValue`. IE - How do you now value `1.23` belongs do `DevCost` and not to `LiceCost`?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I am using Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very arcane data structure.  SQL tables are inherently unordered.  From what I can tell, the SQL value is in the "next" row based on the id.

If so, you can use `lead()`:

```
select . . .,
       stringvalue as fieldname, next_string_value as stringvalue
from (select t.*, lead(t.stringvalue) over (order by id) as next_string_value
      from t
     ) t
where t.objname = 'objname';
```

If you are really using SQL Server 2008, you can use a self-join.  This does assume that the ids have no gaps in them.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. It (LEAD) really helped for my solution.